# how to add each element of an array to the stage as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array with movieclips (r1, r2, etc) and tThose movieclips must been hidden until there is a hitestobject so i have this code at first

```
var replace:Array = [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8]
var len:int = replace.length;
for( var o:int = 0; o < len; o++ )
    this.removeChild( replace[o] );
  replace.length = 0;
```

I want to add each element of that array on stage every time i have a hittestoblect. Something is wrong with my code because only r1 is added on stage and i don't know how to fix it. Can you please help me?

```
 function releaseToDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
 {
     Star(e.target).stopDrag();
     if (Star(e.target).hitTestObject(target))
   {
      removeChild(Star(e.target));
      for(var o:uint = 0;o<7;o++){
      var replace:Array = [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8]
            addChild(replace[0])

 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
addChild(replace[0]);
```

Always adds the first child, to add a specific object, you replace 0 with whatever index you have. If you want to add them one by one, as in one after another every time there's a hit, you should have counter outside of the function that gets incremented every time there's a hit

```
var counter:int = 0;

function releaseToDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   Star(e.target).stopDrag();
   if (Star(e.target).hitTestObject(target))
   {
     removeChild(Star(e.target));
     var replace:Array = [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8]
     addChild(replace[counter]);
     counter = counter+1;
   } 
 }
```

Comment: i did it but all the items of that array show up. I want them one by onelike with the first hittestobject r1 is added on stage with the second hittestobject r2 is added on stage.

Comment: I see, see my edit if I understood the question correctly now... do you want to add them one by one (first hit happens, add r1, second hit happens, add r2)?

Comment: okay, then my edit should work, just make sure that counter is outside of releaseToDrop-function

Comment: i try this code but It did not work. All the items of the array are added once on stage.

Comment: Hmm? Did you remember to remove the for loop? See my yet another edit.

Comment: Thank you. it works. i forgot to remove the for loop. NoW it works perfectly.